# What hardware is required to run this program?

Tags: python, hardware

My main goal here is to get the results from this program for my research programs, so even if someone has a ready database of such a permutation set I could download, it would be helpful to my quest here.

That said, if I could generate it myself, it would be an advantage to what I'm doing.

Program:

```
import itertools
set=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
perm=list(itertools.permutations(set, 12))
print perm
```

The problem I'm running into is a hardware issue.

My hardware specifications are the following:

```
imac 27in late 2012
Mac OSX Mountain Lion
8GB 1600MHz DDR3 RAM
Intel 3.4GHz i7
1TB HD with a bit more than 50% free space.
```

The message I get when I try to run the program is that there is not enough memory on the startup disk to keep the program open and it asks me to force quit the program. It freezes and then I have to fix my permissions after a hard restart to get everything running smooth again, so:

I DO NOT RECOMMEND RUNNING THIS PROGRAM, AS IS, TO TEST IT, unless you already know your system can handle it.

But, my estimation is that this program outputs a list at (I think) size 12! which is ungodly large... over 500,000,000 permutations (the actual size of the output might be less than 12!, but it is way larger than just an exponential).

So, how can I get this data? Do I need a new system? If so, how much space or RAM do I need?

Or, is there some trick I can use to split the program up into manageable chunks?

Comment: What are you gonna do with permutations, want to store somewhere?

Comment: Why convert it to a list? Why not keep it as an iterator?

Comment: @Karthikeyan I want to store it, and also do find and replace type algorithms on it. They will actually be fodder for linear time sub routines over an NP complete problem. I have a hypothesis that this permutation set, when applied to groups of variables in an NP complete problem, will allow for deterministic solving of that problem in P.

Comment: What the heck are you even going to do with a giant list of permutations of letters? It has practically 0 informational content.

Comment: `print perm` = matrix terminal o_O

Comment: @SukritKalra: First, will it store as an iterable? I will test it soon. Second, how can I generate it into a data set? I want to be able to do permutations over it and print it out into text.

Comment: ...oh. You're trying to solve P=NP... with a superexponential-sized giant list of stuff. Even iterating over this thing takes more time than P allows. I don't think you thought this through.

Comment: This question has an XY problem. You do not need more hardware — you need to re-think the program.

Comment: your problem is storing the result (which is huge) into memory and trying to print. try writing directly to disk.

Comment: @user2357112 It's super exponential upon a constant over lin time, so yes I have thought it through quite a bit.

Comment: @bansi how would I write directly to disk?

Comment: If I were you, I would build my own permutator that could be started and stopped. And I would encode the results to take smaller space (you can always expand it later). 12 items means 4 bits per item x 12 = 48 bits, so each permutation would need 6 bytes (maybe round up to 8 or 10) and not the 144 cited below. This reduces your space requirements by a factor of 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each element (12 elements tuple) take approximately 144 bytes according to following test. (Window 7 64bit, Python 2.7.5)

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'))
144
```

Permutation will generate 12! elements.

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,b:a*b, range(1,12+1)) # 12!
479001600
```

It will take about 68GB of memory.

```
144 * 479001600 = 68,976,230,400
```

---

Saving to disk takes about 6+GB. (13 * 479001600 = 6,227,020,800) (1 byte for newline)

```
import itertools

with open('permutations.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines(''.join(xs) + '\n' for xs in itertools.permutations('abcdefghijkl'))
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for http://downloadmoreram.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, but it doesn't solve my permutation and storing problem. I need to iterate over the set so that I can do find and replace, such that a-->a(), b-->b(), c-->c()... and I need to be able to read it. bansi mentioned that I might be able to write directly to disk, I'm not familiar with those functions, so any ideas as to how I can approach writing directly to disk?

Comment: @JMarkInman, Do you want write `abcdefghijkl` ... `lkjihgfedcba` to disk?

Comment: @falsetru yes, and be able to run a limited number of find and replace like changes over that list, because I need to use it 4 times.

Comment: @JMarkInman, I added a code that writes `abcdefghijkl` ... `lkjihgfedcba` line by line.

Comment: @falsetru nice solution. btw I don't know python.